# Как добавить запись в таблицу rbac

Tags: php, yii2, миграция, rbac

есть в yii2 такая вещь как rbac, в ней есть таблица auth_item_child, в ней поля parent и child, в эти поля можно вставить только значения из таблицы auth_item, поля name. Не знаю как это описать, приложу картинку.

[image: картинка]

Так вот, вопрос состоит в следующем, как добавить запись в таблицу auth_item_child через миграции? пробовал так:

```
    $this->insert('auth_item_child', [
        'parent'        => 'item_1',
        'child'         => 'item_2'
    ]);
```

но при выполнении миграции происходит ошибка:

```
    insert into auth_item_child ...Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tag_api_client`.`auth_item_child`, CONSTRAINT `auth_item_child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `auth_item` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `auth_item_child` (`parent`, `child`) VALUES ('auth_item.browsingSummerCeremony', 'auth_item.allowedToSummerCeremony') (/var/www/html/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:664)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таблицы RBAC в Yii 2 записи добавляются только через классы самого RBAC.

В Вашем случае нужно для начала создать роли.

```
$role1 = Yii::$app->authManager->createRole('role1');
$role1->description = 'Роль1';
Yii::$app->authManager->add($role1);
$role2 = Yii::$app->authManager->createRole('role2');
$role2->description = 'Роль2';
Yii::$app->authManager->add($role2);
```

Подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](http://streletzcoder.ru/nastraivaem-dostup-k-web-prilozheniyu-na-osnove-roley-yii-2-chast-1-obshhie-mehanizmyi-rabotyi/).

А, потом для соответствующей роли добавить дочернюю посредством метода [addChild](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager#addChild()-detail).

```
Yii::$app->authManager->addChild($role1,$role2);
```

Comment: спасибо, про это я в курсе, задача в том что бы добавить новые роли не ломая старые и хотел бы как то сделать через миграции, если это возможно по другому, подскажите как?

Comment: а если отойти от rbac и в будущем я захочу добавлять данные в подобные таблицы через миграции, то как быть? Спасибо.

Comment: RBAC это готовый модуль Yii 2 и самодеятельность с его таблицами нежелательна. Да и зачем такой костыль, если уже есть готовый высокоуровнеый интерфейс для работы? Если же RBAC Вас совсем не устраивает, то придётся либо дорабатывать его под себя, либо искать альтернативный модуль (если такие есть), либо писать своё решение для управления учётками пользователей и их правами. Как-то так.

Comment: не так все же если отойти от таблиц rbac, и будет необходимость вставлять данные в таблицу с такими же зависимостями?

Comment: Хотите подменить таблицы RBAC? Зачем?

Comment: Нее, не хочу менять таблицы rbac, просто вдруг встретится какие нибудь таблицы вообще в общем похожие на по структуре